# IntelliJ / WebStorm code style option to retain JSON arrays on a single line

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Consider the following snippet of code that I have manually formatted into the preferred structure. In particular each attribute has *one* line for its value. Even *arrays* have only one (possibly v long) line.

[image]

This is precisely the output format generated by `jsfiddle.net` https://jsfiddle.net/javadba/toq7gby2/

Note that the following - each complete array entry on its own line - would also be a fine result:

[image]

I am looking into whether the following formatted javascript code were possible when using the `Code | Reformat Code` option in the Jetbrains family of IDE's.  In particular the `Settings | Editor | Code Style | Javascript` option to keep line breaks or not:

[image]

This "on" selection results in one of *many* different results depending on how I entered/pasted the JSON originally. It does minimal reformatting. Here is one possible result

[image]

That is actually *too much free style* for me.  I'm looking for that first result - which has all the entries aligned.

The other end of the spectrum happens when we turn off the line breaks:

[image]

Now the result is more compact - actually *too* compact. All entries in a given dict are on the same (possibly huge) line:

[image]

I'm wondering if there were any way to format the JOSN with Name/Value pairs each on their own line - as shown in the first screenshot?

Comment: You can copy your code, then go to the Code Style in setting and paste it in the preview. Now just change the setting and it will use your pasted code right away (so you can preview the changes live).

Comment: Not sure - are you suggesting to update the settings  for each new JSON fragment?   I'm looking for a fixed setting. I can always take the code , go to _JSFiddle_ and then copy it back .. but that's extra work and will get lost if I reformat the entire file down the road.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you can have a LIVE PREVIEW when going through the Code Style configuration (so you can see an instant feedback when changing any of the options).

Comment: I did some testing .. and this is the best when reformatting from the one liner (see `original` file): https://postimg.cc/0ryqRQrj . Some issues: it does not seem to do anything when object has only 1 element (e.g. `"adjusts": {"FICO": .250}`).  If you add a line break after `{` and before `}` then it will keep it as is and will not add them if they are not there (unless it has 2+ elements). Longer arrays may be formatted differently. Can expand array s.. but it then goes into extremes (which is much worse): https://postimg.cc/RJL3H05N ...

Comment: P.S. WebStorm supports Prettier -- maybe it can format as you need? 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html 2) https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html

Comment: @LazyOne can you make your work into an answer? It seems like quite a reasonable "this is the best we can do" result

Comment: Wait for [@lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) (WebStorm support person) to look at this -- she definitely knows better how it all works and what tickets to watch after/what the plans are (in case if it's not implemented)

Answer (score 3):

The closest setup I can suggest is

[image]

but it's not exactly what you are looking for.
So using Prettier for code reformatting seems to be the best way to go:

[image]